# firebase ios snapshot.childrenCount returns default 0 instead of database value

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i've written this code:

```
func countTeacherSubstitutions() -> Int {
    var count: Int = 0
    database.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snap) in
        count = Int(snap.childrenCount)
        print("\(snap.childrenCount) /c")
        print("\(count) /t1")
    })
    print("\(count) /t2")
    return count
    }
```

The fuction should return 4 (childrens at root in database) instead of 0 (default firebase value)

print statements return the following:
"/c: 4"
"/t1: 4"
"/t2: 0"

a link to the github repo (this code isnt pushed yet): https://github.com/bcye/teacher-substitution-schedule-app-webscraper

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: I adde an answer that should fix it. I didn't try my code out in Xcode so the syntax might be off, but I know for certain it will fix it. If you have issues feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this.

Firebase runs on another thread. Whats happening is its saying
Step 1) count = 0
Step 2) Ask firebase for the information, but, this could take some time so go to the next step and we will perform everything inside this brackets when we are done
Step 3) (Happens before stuff in step 2 is called) return Count (which is 0)

What you need to do is either directly update whatever you want to update with the value of count from inside of the firebase closure (where you print the value of c), or send in a completion handler to handle the value of count when it is done.

An example might be this

```
func countTeacherSubstitutions(completion: (Int) -> Void){
database.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snap) in
    count = Int(snap.childrenCount)
    completion(count)
})
}
```

Call the above like so, from wherever.

```
let completion = { (count: Int) in
    //I don't know what you do with count, but for this example ill update a label
    label.text = "\(count)"
}
countTeacherSubstitutions(completion: completion)
```

What essentially happens here is you tell it the code you want to be run once its done doing what its doing, i.e getting data from the server. Without this in place, if it took 2 mins to get data from the server, you'd have to wait 2 mins to use your app.

Comment: Have written the function like this now: https://pastebin.com/J8vRXuyj It doesn't work and Xcode is showing the message that the counter variable in the completion isn't used (while it's used in the while loop)

Comment: @Bruce looking at just that clip of code, it looks like you are trying to access the root of your database + 0, 1, 2 ... count.   Is that how your database is stored?  Also, if you are using the count variable to loop through all the items, there really isn't a need to do that. Instead of doing .value do .childAdded and it should give you each item one by one. On that same note, you could also loop through the snapshots children given to you from the .value.